# Phonegap activityStart in android not showing the messge which I pass

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

In my project I used navigator.notification.activitystart("Title","Message").

But it is just showing the title as "Busy" and message as "Please wait". I can stop the activity with      navigator.notification.activityStop()

So i want to ask does the activityStart really shows the title and message on android phones.

I am using phonegap1.1.0

Thanks all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From both phonegap-1.1.0.js and phonegap-1.3.0.js:

```
Notification.prototype.activityStart = function() {
    PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "Notification", "activityStart", ["Busy","Please wait..."]);
};
```

Note that activityStart takes no parameters, so you'd have to modify it to actually accept your parameters.

Comment: Thanks so much... i didn't realize that they could have make the message hard coded..

Comment: @Paul I am able to start spinner loader in screen but not able to stop it from spinning? navigator.notification.activityStop();this is not working.